# XSD.exe automatically set generated specified field in associated property's setter

Tags: c#, xsd.exe

Is there a way to have XSD.exe automatically set the generated setter field in the setter of the associated property?

For example, take the following [CustomersOrders.xsd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675181.aspx) schema.  If generating C# class files using the `xsd CustomersOrders.xsd /c /n:mynamespace` command, part of the resulting class follows:

```
 /// <remarks/>
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
 public System.DateTime ShippedDate {
     get {
         return this.shippedDateField;
     }
     set {
         this.shippedDateField = value;
     }
 }

 /// <remarks/>
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
 public bool ShippedDateSpecified {
     get {
         return this.shippedDateFieldSpecified;
     }
     set {
         this.shippedDateFieldSpecified = value;
     }
 }
```

What I want is the following

```
 /// <remarks/>
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
 public System.DateTime ShippedDate {
     get {
         return this.shippedDateField;
     }
     set {
         this.shippedDateField = value;
         this.shippedDateFieldSpecified = true;
     }
 }
```

(notice the addition of the `this.shippedDateFieldSpecified = true;` in the setter of the associated property.

I didn't see anything in the help documentation for this.  Thanks!

Comment: How you expect XSD to automagically know that shippedDateFieldSpecified has anything to do with shippedDateField?

Comment: Because the specified fields are generated by XSD and not actually in the schema as a convenience thing.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly need the same. There are Specified property but it just complicate work with nullable props. Yes, if nullable element was chaged, Specified prop should be automatically set to true. I work with large schemas - not small simple, not want change them always. This problem is with xsd.exe years.